# "Invariant Violation" after calling readQuery using apollo angular

Tags: caching, graphql, apollo-angular

I am just testing a simple case where I can add cats and show cat details.
But I am getting this error
`bundle.esm.js:805 Invariant Violation: Can't find field color on object {
  "id": "5cf74600ed38a91e472e0e20",
  "name": "Rose",
  "breed": "Italian",
  "__typename": "Cat"
}`

when I try to update cache after adding a new cat

`this.apollo.mutate<CreateCatMutationResponse>({
      mutation: CREATE_CAT_MUTATION,
      variables: {
        name: this.name,
        breed: this.breed,
        color: this.color
      },
      // awaitRefetchQueries: false,
      update: (store, {data: {createCat}}) => {
        // Read the data from our cache for this query.
        const data: any = store.readQuery({query: cats, variables: {id: createCat.id}});`

```
    // Add our comment from the mutation to the end.
    if (data) {
      data.cats.push(createCat);
    }
    // Write our data back to the cache.
    store.writeQuery({query: cats, data});
  },
}`
```

Its becuse in the page that I am trying to add a new cat shows only 2 properties ie name and breed and not color :

`this.allCat = this.apollo.watchQuery<Query>({
      query: gql`
      query cats {
      cats {
      id
      name
      breed
      }
      }
      `,
      fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network'
    })
      .valueChanges
      .pipe(
        map(result => result.data.cats)
      );
  }`

Any Idea how can I get rid of this issue without using refetch queries?

Comment: Phew, I solved it using fragments.

Comment: It would be really useful if you could share how to solved the issue for others that are new to Apollo

Comment: same answser as @mcgraphix